# ArcMap Label (Python)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

SOLUTION: I was able to do it with help of a colleague by creating a list instead, I'm assuming the tuple was was a quirky bug;

```
def FindLabel ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] ):
lst = ['1"', '2"']
if [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] not in lst:
return [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER]
else:
return None
```

I feel like this should be straight forward but it's turning out to be a pain.

Basically, I have a line feature in ArcMap that has a field (size) that is type double.

I wanted to create a label that would exclude all sizes below 2 (2"). Problem is because the field is based on a domain the field value is 2 but to do the python labeling it seems like they are strings (2 equates to 2" in the domain).

I figured I'd just create a label like this following:

```
def FindLabel ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] ):
if [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] in ('1"', '2"'):
return [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER]
else:
return None
```

and only show the diameter values I wanted to show. The problem is it works fine with those two values (1" and 2");
[image]

but as soon as I add another value I am getting an error;

[image]

I know I could do this fairly easily in a label class but I feel like this should be straight forward to do in a python label too so its kind of bothering me that I cant figure it out. Might anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Please don't include answers (solutions) within the area reserved for questions.  There is a separate area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the value into an integer and then compare it with math operations.

```
def FindLabel ( [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER] ):
   if int([PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER][:-1]) >= 2:
      return [PIPE_INTERNAL_DIAMETER]
```

Much effective, you may have 100 values. What you are gonna do, create a list with 100?